# Is someone trying to attack our API

Tags: aws

I created a service with elastic beanstalk in AWS 2 or 3 hours ago.

EC2 is in private subnet and load balancer is in public subnet.

When I look to logs I saw these requests.

What are they?

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you have a server that's exposed to the Internet, then it is probably getting hit by some automated attacks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Welcome to the internet."

Essentially, every server exposed to the internet will be targetted by countless automated scripts, which try to exploit the low-hanging fruits. These scripts try to exploit common misconfigurations, such as exposing [.env](https://www.acunetix.com/vulnerabilities/web/dotenv-env-file/) or [.git](https://github.com/WangYihang/GitHacker) files/folders publicly.

So to answer the question: Yes, someone is trying to attack your API. Make sure they don't succeed.

Comment: @AuroPick You're welcome. The best way to deal with those is to just make sure you're not vulnerable to any of those attacks. There are plenty of scanners out there, which you can use to check for common attack vectors. These should be good enough to cover the threat posed by automated attack scripts.